# Matlab - Image Segmentation Using Pretrained BodyPix Model

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation

I am looking to use BodyPix 2.0 to segment images from my desktop in Matlab.

The git repository is here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

My end goal would be to output saved photos from Matlab onto my computer in the below format:

[Person Segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc3wj.jpg)

I have installed the deep learning toolbox along with various add-on models such as ResNet50 and MobileNetV2, along with trying to follow this:

https://blogs.mathworks.com/deep-learning/2021/04/16/bringing-tensorflow-models-into-matlab/

Could someone help me understand how to go about doing this? For instance, BodyPix says it supports MobileNetV1 or ResNet50, so this would import the ResNet network:

```
path = pwd;
load('classnames.mat')
net_ResNet50 = importTensorFlowNetwork('ResNet50','OutputLayerType','classification','Classes',classNames)
```

but how do I use/import the BodyPix model specifically along with that?

---

I am currently looking at using the ONNX converter:

```
layers = importONNXLayers(modelfile)
layers = importONNXLayers(modelfile,Name,Value)
```

as it supports conversion to Matlab, but that seems like an extra extra step when Matlab already supports Tensor/Keras models, and I'm still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Someone has voted to close this as a "looking for books, software libraries, or other similar resources" question. I'm not sure that's right, but you should read through [ask]. Also, see the [tag:git] tag popup text, which ends with: *do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository.*

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the feedback on my first question ever, I'll post some of the actual code into the question so it is more obviously a coding question. I thought it would be redundant from a coding tutorial about how to do what I need to do, just with a different model and someone able to help would rather have the source anyway.